# Consistent website rendering across different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm making an old website with HTML.  I used the `reset.css` and I can see this perfectly on the web (http://www.ceachile.cl/revista/) with Chrome, Firefox and IE10, but my client can't see some elements properly.  I don't know what else can I do to fix this table that is in a wrong place. Here's a folder with a lot of screenshots of the site in many browsers and OS.

[Some snapshots of what the website looks like under various browsers can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jpo24m5zy6gt0wl/AAB6rM3L_sC8xW0DMDbDR5vRa)

Comment: From the screenshots it looks like negative margin issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check with elements of HTML and CSS each of the browsers support. Trident has historically been behind in implementing a lot of newer features. If you aim to support older browser, you have to look at their documentation and write code based on what they can handle.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250496(v=vs.85).aspx for ie7.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your client's OS and browser version, you can use a service like [www.browserstack.com](http://www.browserstack.com) to test your website in this environment and debug it with the usual developer tools.